# Operation failed, no current record. Exception class: CDBException, Error: 1007

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ms-access

I created a program which will do an insert operation and edit operation (on the inserted row) in loop.

```
for(i=0 ; i<10 ,i++)
{
insert_into_table();
edit_table();
}
```

insert_`into_table()` will do the insert operation.
The steps I followed are described below:

1. Open Database
2. Open `Table(m_pRecordset->Open(CRecordset::dynaset, strQuery.c_str(),CRecordset::none);)`.
3. Add the `record(m_pRecordset->AddNew();)`.
4. Add the `value(m_pRecordset->Field(szFieldName.c_str()) =  bValue;)`. (`Field()` will return field name.)
5. Update the record set (`m_pRecordset->Update();`).
6. Close `table(m_pRecordset->Close();)`.
7. Close `DataBase`.

In the next statement of the for loop I will do the edit operation on the previously inserted row. The steps I followed described below:

1. Open Database
2. Open `Table(m_pRecordset->Open(CRecordset::dynaset, strQuery.c_str(),CRecordset::none);)`.
3. Edit the recordset(`m_pRecordset->Edit();`).

Here I got an exeption:

> Operation failed, no current record. Exception class: CDBException, Error: 1007

It is only happening when the statements are executed in loop.
How can I resolve this issue? Thanks.